# zoom in UIImageView and UIImageView.center

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiimageview

Trying to zoom in / out an imageView.

i've managed that successfully so now i'm trying to place some buttons on the view and when button tapped to zoom on that area.

How can i implement that?

here is my code so far

```
-(void)zoomHere:(UIButton *)sender{

    NSLog(@"zoom in");
    //[self performSelector:@selector()
    //         withObject:nil
    //         afterDelay:1.6f];


    CGAffineTransform transformer = CGAffineTransformScale(imageView.transform, 1.05, 1.05);



    if (transformer.a < 5) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.2];
        imageView.transform = transformer;
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }


}
```

and the view did load

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *buttonView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(00.0, 20.0, 768, 1004.0)];

    zoomHere = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [zoomHere addTarget:self
               action:@selector(zoomHere:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [zoomHere setTitle:@"ZoomIN" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    zoomHere.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [buttonView addSubview:zoomHere];

    buttonView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:buttonView];


}
```

It still zoom in but not on that area where the button sits on screen!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to use scale transform, you probably should use translate transform as well
like this:

```
CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.05, 1.05);
CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(10, 20);
CGAffineTransform delta = CGAffineTransformConcat(scale, translate);
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(imageView.transform, delta);
```

this is how you know the position of button on your image view:

```
[imageView convertPoint:button.center fromView:self.view]
```

so if you know button's coordinates and your current scale then you can calculate new translate transform
But as for me, i would rather use scroll view to zoom in and zoom out that image view. You can have nice bouncing animations and zooming animations, also you can have pan and pinch, but of cource it is up to you.

Comment: yeah i tried that too, but could't place the buttons above the scroll view and keep them in place when zoom in out

Comment: that destroys my zoom out function with pinch

Comment: also on the second command i get .view not found on object of type imageView

Comment: oh sorry, it should be just imageView without .view and it should use self.view because your button belongs there

Comment: can you please share picture what you are trying to do? I might have another solution though

Comment: i have that image and want to zoom in on button tapped without making buttons larger and them keeping their place http://i47.tinypic.com/1198e3t.jpg

Comment: than i guess you should have a `scrollView` and those buttons should be on your `controller.view` above your scrollView. you have to disable user actions on the scroll as well. So when user taps a button you just have to do something like `[scrollView zoomToRect:someRect animated:YES];` and if you want to calculate a rect based on a button's position then use `[scrollView convertPoint:button.center fromView:self.view]`. Hope that will help.

Comment: that's how i finally did it. thanks a lot for your help! I'll post the code as soon as as possible!